# What is the max amount of simultaneous connections for Firestore?

Tags: firebase, max, google-cloud-firestore, simultaneous

I know that the max number of simultaneous connections for Firebase's real-time database is ~100,000, but what about for Firestore?

For example, how many users could actively listen for document changes on a document? What is the "comfortable" limit for this (not just the theoretical max)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [Quotas and Limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) from the Cloud Firestore docs. That is and will remain the authoritative answer. Currently (during beta), 1M concurrent connections is the limit, but the number may/will change once it reaches general availability.

Comment: It (the link provided in the answer) states: `Maximum concurrent connections for mobile/web clients per database (at beta) = 1,000,000`, maybe it did change over time? A short followup what section of the `Quotas` displays this value (within `App Engine Quotas`)?

Comment: Define 'per database' ?

Comment: you can have multiple databases within firestore, so per database means 1mill connections ... well, per database. Hitting max concurrent connections a pretty extreme situation to be in, so by the time it becomes an issue (if ever) it wont be a big deal since you'll see it coming and (hopefully) have expertise on hand to solve it.

Comment: Is there a view to monitor the number of concurrent connections